# Setting Binary Constraints with Google OR-tools

Tags: python, or-tools

I have been using OR-tools, in particular looking at its uses for scheduling. I feel I have grasp on the library now, though there is one aspect of Google's main example ( https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/master/examples/python/shift_scheduling_sat.py ) that I am having trouble understanding. The function I am having a problem with is: `add_soft_sequence_constraint()` and the related: `negated_bounded_span` (relevant code is below).

These are meant to constrain the number of shifts a person can work in a row though I cannot figure out how this is accomplished.

My issues are: What exactly is the result of using .Not()? I am having trouble locating any documentation on it or producing a clear test for it. Why is `negated_bounded_space()` (a function that depends on .Not()) necessary at all? Finally, in both cases in `add_soft_sequence_constraint` how does it know the difference between you working one long sequence (ie, 6 shifts in a row) which would not be allowed and 2 shorter sequences (4 shifts, a break, then 3 shifts) which may be allowed but adds up to the same (or more) as the long sequence?

Any help would be great and much appreciated, I would like to be able to use and adapt the code but I feel uncomfortable doing so before properly understanding it.

```
def negated_bounded_span(works, start, length):
    sequence = []
    # Left border (start of works, or works[start - 1])
    if start > 0:
        sequence.append(works[start - 1])
    for i in range(length):
        sequence.append(works[start + i].Not())
    # Right border (end of works or works[start + length])
    if start + length < len(works):
        sequence.append(works[start + length])
    return sequence

def add_soft_sequence_constraint(model, works, hard_min, soft_min, min_cost,
                                 soft_max, hard_max, max_cost, prefix):

    # Forbid sequences that are too short.
    for length in range(1, hard_min):
        for start in range(len(works) - length - 1):
            model.AddBoolOr(negated_bounded_span(works, start, length))


    # Just forbid any sequence of true variables with length hard_max + 1
    for start in range(len(works) - hard_max - 1):
        model.AddBoolOr(
            [works[i].Not() for i in range(start, start + hard_max + 1)])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To elaborate on the answer of Laurent:

If you want to avoid sequences of length 2 in a list of length 4:

- `[1,1,0,0]` -> `BoolOr[v0.Not(),v1.Not(),v2]`
- `[0,1,1,0]` -> `BoolOr[v0, v1.Not(), v2.Not(), v3]`
- `[0,0,1,1]` -> `BoolOr[v1, v2.Not(), v3.Not()]`

I also openned a issue of Github https://github.com/google/or-tools/issues/1399, as the line

```
for start in range(len(works) - length - 1):
```

may be wrong.

Small example for a list of length 4 and hard min of 3:

```py
from ortools.sat.python import cp_model


def negated_bounded_span(works, start, length):
    sequence = []
    # Left border (start of works, or works[start - 1])
    if start > 0:
        sequence.append(works[start - 1])
    for i in range(length):
        sequence.append(works[start + i].Not())
    # Right border (end of works or works[start + length])
    if start + length < len(works):
        sequence.append(works[start + length])
    return sequence


if __name__ == '__main__':
    model = cp_model.CpModel()
    works = [model.NewBoolVar(f'{i}') for i in range(4)]
    for length in range(1, 3):
        print(f'Length {length}')
        for start in range(len(works) - length + 1):
            print(negated_bounded_span(works, start, length))
```

Returns something along the lines of:

```
Length 1
[0.Not(), 1(0..1)]
[0(0..1), 1.Not(), 2(0..1)]
[1(0..1), 2.Not(), 3(0..1)]
[2(0..1), 3.Not()]
Length 2
[0.Not(), 1.Not(), 2(0..1)]
[0(0..1), 1.Not(), 2.Not(), 3(0..1)]
[1(0..1), 2.Not(), 3.Not()]
```

Comment: thank you, that has cleared a lot up for me. I have one follow up question now I understand slightly better. For the hard max case, you only ever apply .Not() to sequences that are len(hardMax + 1) - wont this then allow sequences that are len(hardMax + 2) and longer, even though these should be constrained to?

Comment: Well, a sequence of len(hardMax + 2) must contain a sequence of len(hardMax + 1) so that should be impossible

Comment: @Stradivari What should I do if I need only sequences of length 2 in a list of length n?

Comment: @sg7610 bool[i] implies bool[i-1] or bool[i+1], i-1 and i implies not(i+1), i+1 and i implies not(i-1)

Answer (score 3):

Not() is the negation of a Boolean variable.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem.

The main idea is that if you want to forbid a given pattern:

v0 = false, v1 = true, v2 = true, v3 = false

That is a sequence of length 2 starting at position 1, you add a BoolOr specifying that v0 is true, or v1 is false, or v2 is false, or v3 is true.

If any one of these condition is true, then this particular pattern is not present.

This is written as

> BoolOr([v0, v1.Not(), v2.Not(), v3])

.